# Different behavior between running command with sudo or directly as superuser - PATH is same

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, sudo, java

I'm trying to install eclipse on xubuntu, I installed java with `sudo gdebi <java-package>.deb`, I added it to the `/etc/environment` to both `PATH` and "JAVA_HOME" then reloaded the environment and also rebooted the whole system.

running `java --version` I got the correct output

```
java 12.0.1 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

both if called by superuser

```
$ sudo su
# java --version
```

or by

```
$ java --version
```

but running

```
$ sudo java --version
```

I got `java: command not found`

but running

```
sudo echo $PATH
```

I got

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/:/snap/bin/`

and path to java is present: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/`

How can I fix it?
also could someone explain my why this happens?

Comment: Can you `sudo su` and provide output `echo $PATH` in active session. Try to run java by absolute path in active sudo session.

Comment: `sudo echo $PATH` would expand `$PATH` before `sudo` is called. It would be better to use something like `sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'` (note the quoting).

Comment: That's why I ask @DDS to provide `echo` in active session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the PATH is being overwritten by sudo.

You should check to see if `/etc/sudoers` contains a `secure_path=...` setting and ads your java path to this.

---

Be wary of simple tests.  To confirm your path you should:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

The simpler form `sudo echo $PATH` does not work because `PATH` is expanded before `sudo` is invoked.

Comment: See edit: `$ sudo echo $PATH`, `$ echo $PATH` and `# echo $PATH` all are the same and contains java path, only difference is absence of `/snap/bin` in 'root' call

Comment: @DDS edited, still *do check* your `/etc/sudoers` for a `secure_path`.

Comment: I did, you are right! I added java path to secure path and it now works!